# Iframe content doesn't show on IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, doctype

We have a plugin which displays content on other websites using an iFrame. In IE 8 and 9, if there's a `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the parent's page, then the iframe loads, but its content remains blank.

Removing the `DOCTYPE` from the parent solves this.

I can't go around telling all the people using the plugin not to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` or to use something else, so I have to find another solution.

I own the code loading the iframe and the code inside the iframe, so any solution which is using these will be welcomed...

Comment: Solution: DROP SUPPORT.

Comment: I wish I could, but that's not an option at the moment...

Comment: Is your plugin attempting to manipulate the content of the iframe in any way? Are you able to supply an example of what it's doing?

Comment: My plugin basically loads the iframe, which contains our own content, and then embeds it in the page. I also change the iframe's height to make sure it fits its content height, but that's about it. Basically - the parent page is someone else's, and they use our script to embed our iframe.

Comment: Is there anything you can say about the content to help us figure out why it is not loading

Comment: Is it really empty (when you inspect it using the DOM inspector)? Or is the content invisible? The first would point towards things like HTTP/HTTPS mismatch, the second towards CSS styling issues involving the height.

Comment: From some further reading and testing, I think it might have to do with some incompatible content, and I'm looking into it. It seems weird to me that if there's one or more incompatibility then the entire content will be blank.

Comment: _“I also change the iframe's height to make sure it fits its content height”_ – and how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: I'm setting a listener outside the iframe, and I let it know using postMessage whenever the content's height changes. The listener then adjusts the css on the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `<!DOCTYPE>`, it might help you avoid overflowing IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
```

Try adding this `<meta>` tag in your `<head>` tags:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

That can also help you:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Put it after the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` tag.

You could use [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file.

Comment: Thanks, the meta tag was the one to do it. It's still a problem, because I can't add it dynamically and I have to ask the site's owner to add the tag themselves. I wish there was some way to solve this on runtime

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem was using display: table on the iframe. In IE7 & 8 it caused the entire content to disappear completely. @rolory's meta tag solution solves this, but I was afraid that it may also cause issues with the parent's content.

Thanks everyone for the help.